# How to remove all cross-sell product links from Magento?

Tags: database, magento, product

I want to remove all of the cross-sell product links from the store - we have around 22,000 links that was the result of an auto cross sell extension that I have since removed.

I imagine it has something to do with removing records from the table catalog_product_link?

Or is there a way to do this programmatically?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are right, removing records is the fastest way to do this. Start by looking at `catalog_product_link_type` and find the `link_type_id` for "cross_sell". It's usually "5" but there is no reason to take a chance.
Backup your database.
Delete all records from `catalog_product_link` with a matching `link_type_id`. An SQL like this should work:

```
DELETE FROM `catalog_product_link` WHERE `link_type_id` = 5;
```

Comment: Thanks clockworkgeek. I ended up running this query first, and then yours. It worked well: delete FROM `catalog_product_link_attribute_int` WHERE link_id in 
(select link_id from `catalog_product_link` where link_type_id = 5);

Answer (score 1):

if you would rather not edit the database directly, you could use the free extension from TBT called [Mass Product Relater](http://www.magentocommerce.com/extension/549/mass-product-relater).  That will allow you to strip out product relationships from the Manage Products grid.